# Does writing to a dev/sys file spin off a child process?

Tags: c, popen

I have some device which has a sysfs driver. Before doing anything else, I need to configure the device by writing the contents of a file, "configs.txt", to a file in the sysfs directory for the subsystem. This can successfully be done with

```
cat /home/configuration/configs.txt > /sys/bus/iio/devices/device3/config
```

If enter this command in a terminal, it takes about 5 seconds for the next shell prompt to be printed.  I take that to mean that whatever the sysfs driver is doing takes about 5 seconds to complete.

However, if I try to use `popen()` as follows:

```
int main(void){
    FILE *file;
    char terminal[512];

    if(!(file=popen("cat /home/configuration/configs.txt > /sys/bus/iio/devices/device3/config", "r"))){return -1;}

    while(fgets(terminal,sizeof(terminal),file)!=NULL){
        printf("%s\n",terminal);
    }

    pclose(file);
    printf("Done\n");
}
```

then the program immediately prints "Done" and exits.  I would like it to wait until the configuration is done, and the rapid program termination relative to executing the same command from an interactive shell seems to indicate that it does not do so.

I guess that `popen()` considers the completion of the `cat` command as being the end of the process, and thus ends the `popen()` and moves on. It does not consider whatever the sysfs driver is doing as part of this, and doesn't wait for it.

My thought was that perhaps it's spinning off a second child process to do this, however I don't know how to verify this, or how to make my program wait for that second child process to complete before continuing.

How can I monitor this and wait for that program to conclude?

Comment: I don't understand. This page https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm seems to indicate that fgets does return NULL once the end of execution is reached and there is no more to read from the terminal.

Comment: The `cat` process you are spanning is not going to write anything to `stdout`. The prompt you are getting after that  command line is from the shell, not from the `cat`. So don't expect any output from it.

Comment: What would be a different way for me to detect when the processing done by the sysfs driver is completed?

Answer (score 1):

**Use `pclose()`**

A pipe opened with `popen()` should be closed with `pclose()`. It also blocks execution until the child process is finished:

> The  pclose()  function  waits  for  the  associated  process  to
>   terminate and returns the exit status of the command as returned by
>   wait4(2).

But it's quite useless, since nothing ever will come back through that pipe. So it'd be better to

**use `system()`**

it starts your process and waits until it completes, all in one function call. The problem is, that when there's an error, your program can't tell what went wrong. You get an exit status back, but it doesn't tell whether e.g. the source or destination file was missing.

The best way would be to

**do it all yourself**

You can open `config.txt` and the file in sysfs by yourself, and copy over the contents. Be sure to close them both afterwards, and examine the return value at each step, that way you'll exactly know what went wrong when it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Although my example doesn't have any output, there IS an output for error messages. For example, if the configurations listed in the config.txt file aren't acceptable. So in the best case I could use system, but in the worst case I want to catch the error message, hence me wanting popen. However, I already am using pclose, which is why I am confused that the program closes prematurely.

Comment: Whoops, shouldn't have answered a question before reading it through:) Anyway, there are about a hundred ways a command and it's invocation through the shell can go wrong, we don't even know if the cat process has been started or not. According to `man popen`, checking the return value doesn't even tell you if a _shell_ could be started at all.

Comment: I just tried modifying my program by appending a ' && echo done' to the command in popen, and that ends up getting printed out, so it seems like it is calling the command properly. But it still goes very fast.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess that `popen()` considers the completion of the `cat` command as
>   being the end of the process, and thus ends the `popen()` and moves on.
>   It does not consider whatever the sysfs driver is doing as part of
>   this, and doesn't wait for it.

*The shell* considers completion of the `cat` command as being the end of the process.  Your driver apparently causes that to take several seconds.

*Your program*, on the other hand, monitors the the pipe from the process executing your command.  When the write end of that pipe is closed, that, quite naturally, indicates the end of the `popen()`ed file has been reached.  `fgets()` will return `NULL` in response, breaking the loop.  Because your command redirects its standard output to a file, that happens right away.

> My thought was that perhaps it's spinning off a second child process
>   to do this, however I don't know how to verify this, or how to make my
>   program wait for that second child process to complete before
>   continuing.

`popen()` *does* launch a child process.  It would be silly to interpose an additional one, and in any case, doing so would not solve the fundamental problem in your approach.

Your simplest approach might be to use `system()` instead of `popen()`.  Like the shell, `system()` will wait for the completion of the command you pass to it, rather than monitoring its output.  There's no output to be expected anyway (see above), so the `popen()` is pretty pointless.

On the other hand, since you don't want to do anything but wait until the job is done anyway, why not just do it directly?  Have your program open the two files,copy the contents of one into the other, and close them both.  Or consider having your program generate the configuration data internally instead of reading it from a separate file.

> How can I monitor this and wait for that program to conclude?

The `system()` command will do this for you.  If you `fork()` a child process to do the work, then you can await its completion via `wait()` or `waitpid()`.  If you write directly to the target sysfs file then after having successfully closed that file, your program will have as much assurance as `cat` could provide of the configuration having been completed.

Comment: Although in the case I offered there is no output, there can be. The sysfs driver can print an error message if something goes wring, which is why I want popen, so I can catch that error message if one comes up. This is why I was avoiding the system() call. In the ideal case I don't need it, but in the worst case I want to catch the error message.

Comment: No, you can't. There is no way for a device driver to print something to the standard output of a user process, that you can catch with `popen()`. But even if it somehow managed to do it, the standard output of `cat` is redirected back to it's configuration interface, and the standard error is not captured by `popen()`. A driver can output something to the system log, which can be configured to print it to the console, that may happen to be your terminal.

Comment: @Craig any messages emitted by the driver *cannot* be going to `cat`'s standard output, and therefore will not be read by your `popen()`'d file anyway.  In any case, you should find that the shell spawned by `system()` inherits its parent's standard streams.  If the driver is writing to either standard output or (more likely) standard error, then `system()` may well do what you want naturally.  Even more so if the driver is writing directly to the user's terminal.

Comment: @Craig, most likely of all, however, your driver is writing to *the system console*.  If you're logged in on the console then that might cause some confusion, but in this case you will not easily interfere with the driver's behavior, nor easily send the output anywhere else.